# Debowerify not working with Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower, browserify

I installed debowerify in my project and added its transform in my Gruntfile.js, here's a snippet:

```
grunt.initConfig({

        browserify: {
            app: {
                files: { 'public/javascripts/build/app.js': ['public/javascripts/app.js'] },
                options: { 
                    transform: ['node-underscorify','debowerify'] 
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Then I installed a module (e.g. bower install bootstrap --save).

In my app.js file I tried to include that module:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

... and got:

> Running "browserify:home" (browserify) task Error: module "bootstrap" not found

My folder structure looks like that:

```
/
- app/
- bower_components/
   - bootstrap/
- node_modules/
- public/
   - javascript/
      - app.js
   - build/
- app.js
- bower.json
- Gruntfile.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my debowerify setup (without node-underscorify) in https://github.com/mallim/browserify_angular_minify

At the same time, I will suggest that instead of

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

I will try

```
require('bootstrap');
```